# Cluster tabular data with text in some columns

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, clustering, pytorch

Let's say I have a following features in the my dataframe:

| user_id | user_age | is_student | is_graduate | salary | resume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| integer | integer | binary | binary | integer | text (up to 1000 symbols) |

And also a few more categorical and numeric features.

I want to cluster my data based on the given data. I could've just use K-Means, however I want to include **resume** column in my data. **Is there a way to include text column in any clustering algorithm?**

One idea I have is to get vector embeddings for each resume observation, then cluster them, and then add those cluster_id to the initial data. This way the text data will be somehow used.

Another idea is to use TF-IDF. Let's say I will create 100 more binary features (words from TF-IDF). This way I can run K-Means straightforwardly on the new data, but this way my dataframe increases dramatically and the clustered data might be hard to interpret.